# How to get the size of folder with fo o.bar name with bash?

Tags: bash, namespaces, find, subdirectory, du

I'm trying to get the size of folders "fo o1.bar fo o2.bar..."
I tried a lot of complex thing but never find a way to do it, atm I'm trying :

```
find /my/folder -maxdepth 1 -name *bar -type d -exec du -ch '{}' \;
```

But I'm getting :

```
12G /my/folder/fo O1.bar
12G /my/folder/fo O1.bar/subdirectoy
43G /my/folder/fo O2.bar
```

I don't want to get the subdirectory size, I have tried with -maxdepth 0 but then the command gives no result.

I would like to get :

```
12G /my/folder/fo O1.bar
43G /my/folder/fo O2.bar
```

Or even ideally just:

```
12G fo-O1.bar
43G fo-O2.bar
```

Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-s` flag of `du` command:

```
find /my/folder -maxdepth 1 -name '*.bar' -type d -exec du -sh '{}' \;
```

As per `man du`:

```
  -s, --summarize
          display only a total for each argument
```

Comment: That was so simple ? I was sure I was missing something out. Thank you a lot buddy !